# OpenGL multiply ProjectionMatrix and ModelMatrix

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es

I'm learning OpenGL programming on Android at the moment and now I'm at the point where I have to use a `ModelMatrix` and a `ProjectionMatrix`. If I understand it right I have three different matrix in OpenGL:

1. ProjectionMatrix which creates the 3D efect (does not change while running the app)
2. ModelMatrix with this I can move objects around
3. ViewMatrix with which I can move all objects around (Camera)

Now in my tutorial book OpenGL ES 2 for Androud: A Quick-Start Guide) the `ProjectionMatrix` and the `ModelMatrix` are multiplied to one single matrix. But I do not understand why. Is that the correct way? With the `ModelMatrix` I can move objects around so why should I multiplay it with an other matrix? Would be great if you can help me to better understand the different matrix in OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're used to taking your vertex, left-multiplying it by a model matrix to rotate it/scale it/move it around in the world, then left-multiplying it by a view matrix to get its position relative to the camera, then left-multiplying it by a projection matrix to get that "3d effect".

In other words, you're taking your vertex **v**, then doing this to it:
**v'** = P * V * M * **v**, where in **v'**, x and y is the pixel location on the screen, and z is the "depth" of the vertex.

But matrix multiplication (whether its a 4x4 matrix or a 4x1 matrix/vector) is associative, meaning:

A * B * v is the same thing as (A * B) * v, where A and B are matrices and v is some vector.

So instead of taking a thousand or so vertices and then multiplying it by M, then V, then P, why not pre-multiply M, V, and P once to create an *MVP matrix* then multiply every vertex by that? That way, when your vertex shader runs on each vertex, it only has to do one matrix multiplication rather than three.

Though I am not sure why your tutorial would be multiplying only the model matrix and the perspective matrix. Is there a view matrix present?

Comment: Okay thank you for that. So you mean that I can only use one matrix? So am I right that I use mRotate, mTranslate and so on to move the camera and multiply the position(x,y,z) of an object with the matrix to move an object around? It is not really clear for me that all this can be done by one matrix.

Comment: mRotate and mTranslate should be used to move the **object** around, not the camera. You use things like mRotate, mTranslate, mScale to create a model matrix. The purpose of this model matrix is to put your object in the correct position and orientation in the world. Once you have a model matrix, you can left-multiply it by a view matrix and a perspective matrix, to get that MVP matrix that I was talking about.

Comment: Ah okay but I hopefully do not need an own model matrix for each object in my sceen?

Comment: No, every object needs their own model matrix. Let's say you have three objects: a human, a cat, and a table in your world. They are all located in different spots and are facing different directions. You need to generate a model matrix for each of them, using mTranslate and mRotate as appropriate. They can all use the same view matrix and perspective though. So each object has its "own" MVP matrix. Doing it this way requires a little more Android code, but it makes your vertex shader run faster.

Comment: Ah okay thank you now I unterstand this much better. But is this not very memory intensive? So I give each sceneElement an own model matrix and multiply it with the VP matrix every onRenderFrame() call? Then it makes sense for me save the VP matrix as one matrix. Do I have to calculate the VP matrix each call of onRenderFrame too? So these methods must be very optimimised to run so fast. And let's say I have 60 sceneElements in my sceene. So I have 60 4x4 matrix?

Comment: Yes, you need to calculate the VP matrix every frame, because the view changes (unless your camera does not move/rotate). 60 4x4 matrices is not really that much memory. But you should not be storing the model matrix anyway. Every frame, you should be generating a model matrix for each object (based on its current position/orientation), making an MVP matrix, upload the MVP matrix to the shader, draw that object, then repeat for the other 59 objects.

Comment: Okay thank you for this detailed discussion here. That helped me a lot to understand the things much clearer. Thank you for that.